# Dozer: JAXBElements to Java Types?

Tags: types, jaxb, type-conversion, dozer

I'm trying (with Dozer) to convert a JAXB DTO to a POJO (well, actually, to a JPA-annotated Hibernate entity before persisting it). The problem right now is that right now Dozer does not seem to convert elements from the JAXB JAXBElement<> type to the JAXBElement.getValue() type.  So, for example, a JAXBElement s is translated to the POJO as JAXBElement, not java.lang.String.  Property names are common; the JAXBElement wrapper is the only difference.

Is there an easy way to do this without writing a custom converter to handle JAXB->java type transition?  It seems like a straightforward thing, so I feel I must be missing something.  The Dozer FAQ mentions only POJO->JAXB, not the other way around...

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that Dozer does not fully implement latest JAXB spec, but should do so in future releases.  See the Dozer guys response to the question [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dozer/forums/forum/452530/topic/3494867), and the submitted feature request [here](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=2919058&group_id=133517&atid=727371).  For now, you have to implement a generic field-level converter that will transform a jaxb-wrapped type into its native java value.

Answer (score 0):

I just create a new pull-request thats resolve this issue, look at:
https://github.com/DozerMapper/dozer/pull/101

or review this in my personal fork, at:
https://github.com/pepebarragan/dozer